# Generating a set of valid parentheses in C++

Tags: java, recursion

Given a number, say `n`, I need to output the *valid* set of parentheses.  I found the following code online and wish to understand it better since it is more efficient than mine:

```
public List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    backtrack(list, "", 0, 0, n);
    return list;
}

public void backtrack(List<String> list, String str, int open, int close, int max){

    if(str.length() == max*2){
        list.add(str);
        return;
    }

    if(open < max)
        backtrack(list, str+"(", open+1, close, max);
    if(close < open)
        backtrack(list, str+")", open, close+1, max);
}
```

Thus, given the input `n=3`, I expect it to generate the following set of parentheses:

> ["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]

I am more or less able to understand *what* he has done; but not *how* and *why* he has done it.  I had two questions specifically:

1. Why does he call it backtracking?  Where exactly is backtracking used in this?
2. I understand how the first output string `((()))` is generated; but how are the rest of them generated?

Thanks!

Comment: @DimChtz, I am extremely sorry.  I did that in a hurry.  Actually the code that I learn from is in Java, but I myself implement it in C++.  Hence the goof up.  Apologies.

Comment: Could you show us your current C++ implementation, for the sake of comparison?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I definitely could; but that is not my intent.  I wish to understand this one because he has done it more succinctly and efficiently.  And more than that, I think I could use this method in a generic way and apply it to other questions especially involving trees.

Comment: How do you know it's more efficient?

Comment: @shmosel, because this one recurses only twice.  Anyway, I am not sure how this would help in solving my doubt.

Comment: i would suggest that you take a paper and a pencil and work as a computer for a while, tracing how the recursion goes. you might understand it better. May be start with n == 2.

Comment: @Serge, yes, indeed.  I did that, and came up with only `((()))`.  Didn't fully understand wherein the other values came up from.

Comment: Let's provide reference to the original author of this code: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/8724/easy-to-understand-java-backtracking-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why the helper method is called `backtrack`.

As for how the strings are generated, `backtrack` is a recursive method, so ...

The first time it is called, `str = ""`, `open < max` and `close = open`, so only one recursive call to backtrack is executed.

Now `str = "("`, `open < max` and `close < open` so both recursive calls are made.

In one call `str = "(("` and in the other `str = "()"`. In the first call `open < max` and `close < open` so both recursive calls are made. In the other call `open < max` and `close = open` so only one recursive call is made.

Now we have 3 calls, `str = (((`, `str = "(()` and `str = "()("`, and the process continues and I think it's clear how all the permutations are created.

Comment: Nicely explained.  Thank you.  One qq - for understand recursion, is it necessary to understand how the recursive calls are made, or can the recursive function be treated as a black box?

Comment: Function calls are placed on a stack. You call the function for the first time and that call is placed on the stack. When the function calls itself, that call is placed on the stack. When that function calls itself again, that call is placed on the stack. Now the stack is 3 high. The recursion ends when `str.length() == max*2`, no more recursive calls are made, and the function calls on the stack start "unwinding" and returning from last to first. It is possible to recurse too deeply and fill up the stack with too many function calls before the recursion ends - a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Had to re-write your java program in c++ as the following. Sorry, got rid of the list. It prints out every step in the recursion. Hope it would make your understanding better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void backtrack(string str, int open, int close, int max);

void generateParenthesis(int n) {
  cout << "Generating parenthesises for n = " << n << endl;
  backtrack( "", 0, 0, n);
}

void backtrack(string str, int open, int close, int max){

  if(str.length() == max*2){
    cout << "==> " << open << " " << close << ": \"" << str << "\"" << endl;
    return;
  }
  cout << "+++ " << open << " " << close << ": \"" << str << "\"" << endl;

  if(open < max)
    backtrack(str+"(", open+1, close, max);
  if(close < open)
    backtrack(str+")", open, close+1, max);
}

int main() {
  generateParenthesis(3);
  return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:

```
$ ./p1
Generating parenthesises for n = 3
+++ 0 0: ""
+++ 1 0: "("
+++ 2 0: "(("
+++ 3 0: "((("
+++ 3 1: "((()"
+++ 3 2: "((())"
==> 3 3: "((()))"
+++ 2 1: "(()"
+++ 3 1: "(()("
+++ 3 2: "(()()"
==> 3 3: "(()())"
+++ 2 2: "(())"
+++ 3 2: "(())("
==> 3 3: "(())()"
+++ 1 1: "()"
+++ 2 1: "()("
+++ 3 1: "()(("
+++ 3 2: "()(()"
==> 3 3: "()(())"
+++ 2 2: "()()"
+++ 3 2: "()()("
==> 3 3: "()()()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your original code, I can't speak to its comparative efficiency, but I can explain how the Java code works. Let's break down the recursive part of the code.

```
public void backtrack(List<String> list,
                      String str,
                      int open,
                      int close,
                      int max) {
```

Our function is going to take five arguments. The first argument is going to be used as an *out* argument, which means we'll be storing results into it. Then we take the string so far, the number of open parens, and the number of close parens. Finally, we take the maximum length, which should remain constant.

```
if(str.length() == max*2){
    list.add(str);
    return;
}
```

This is the base case. It's the easy part. The  variable `max` stores the number of parenthesis pairs, so if the string we're building has length `max * 2`, we have `max` open parens and `max` close parens, meaning we have a completed string. So we add the current string to our accumulator list and stop recursing.

```
if(open < max)
    backtrack(list, str+"(", open+1, close, max);
```

Now, if we have fewer open parentheses than `max` says we're allowed to, we should try adding a new open parenthesis. Calling `backtrack` here with these arguments will append an open paren to the string, then do all of the possible combinations for the rest of the string (modifying the list argument in-place in the process), and then return to this point in the code.

```
if(close < open)
    backtrack(list, str+")", open, close+1, max);
```

Next, if we have fewer close parens than open parens, we also want to try adding a close paren to the end of the string. This `backtrack` call will try every possibility with that close paren added, and add all of the successful results to the accumulator list.

The trick here is that we're passing the accumulator down our call stack multiple times. The list itself is passed *by reference*, since it's a Java object. So, in reality, there's only one single `List` object being passed around, and every time we do `list.add(str)`, it adds the current result to this "global-ish" list. Then, when we get to the end of the method you call `generateParenthesis`, all we have to do is return this list object that we've been mutating all this time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Could you please elaborate the _tricky part_?  It is the exact clarification that I seek.

Comment: Edited. Is that the sort of explanation you're looking for?

Comment: Also, it occurs to me based on your comment on the question a few moments ago that you may not be understanding this: a lot of the time, *both of the if-statements are being called in one step*. There's no `else if`, so if both if-statements are true, they'll both be called and both possibilities will be tried.